# Duplicated email sent to sender and recipient when trying to sending multiple email at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I am trying to send all email at once using gmail service, the email has been sent successfully. However, both sender and recipient gets the same email.

When I am trying to send a single email (not multiple), only recipient who gets the email (which is correct).

Why it is like that?

Here is the code that I am currently using:

Let's say in the ***UserRepository***, there are ***11 users*** that needs system to send the email.

1. Single email only received by recipient. <-- Correct
2. Multiple emails received by both parties (sender and recipient) <-- Wrong

**SendingEmail class:**

```
IEnumerable<UserRepository> multipleModels;
UserRepository model;

protected void SingleEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendSingleEmail(model);
}

protected void MultipleEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMultipleEmail(multipleModels);
}

private void SendSingleEmail(UserRepository repository)
{
    string email = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Email/Languages/{0}/Email.html", repository.EmailLanguage)));
    UserManager.SendSingleEmail(repository, email);
}

private void SendMultipleEmail(IEnumerable<UserRepository> repository)
{
    foreach (var models in repository)
    {
        string email = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Email/Languages/{0}/Email.html", models.EmailLanguage)));
        UserManager.SendMultipleEmail(models, email);
    }
}
```

The code to send the email in **UserManager** class:

```
public static void SendSingleEmail(UserRepository repository)
{
    string toEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevEmail"].ToString();
    string toName = "Email";
    string subject = "Single Subject Email";   
    EmailHelper.SendEmail(0, repository.Email, repository.Name, toEmail, toName, subject, repository.Description);
}

public static void SendMultipleEmail(UserRepository repository, string description)
{
    string fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevEmail"].ToString();
    string fromName = "Nies";
    string subject = "Multiple Subject Email";
    EmailHelper.SendEmail(1, fromEmail, fromName, repository.Email, repository.Name, subject, description);
}
```

**EmailHelper class:**

```
public static void SendEmail(int id, string fromEmail, string fromName, string toEmail, string toName, string subject, string description)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(toEmail, toName);
        string address = (id == 0 ? toAddress.Address : fromAddress.Address);
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mail"].ToString(),
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(address, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DevPassword"].ToString())
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = description,
            Priority = MailPriority.High,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        })    
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What debug showed ?

Comment: Why are **SendSingleEmail** and **SendMultipleEmail** different internally?  I would reconsider the design.  Have a single IEnumerable of UserRepo and a single method that is responsible for sending the email.  Let it loop over the repo and send out however many there are.